# Laravel 8 FontAwesome Incorrect Directory

Tags: font-awesome, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I've just tried to add FontAwesome to one of my Laravel 8 projects (using TailwindCSS). I've installed it using

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Then added it to `./resources/css/app.css` (with my TailwindCSS imports)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/regular.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands.css';
```

Then applied the build with

```
npm run production
```

However it is giving me a 404 Error regarding the font files. They are correctly sitting inside the `./public/fonts` directory but the compiled css file is looking for them in the web servers root directory.

If I manually change the compiled css file to replace

```
src: url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.eot?08f9891a6f44d9546678133ab121fc54);
```

with

```
src: url(../fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-regular-400.eot?08f9891a6f44d9546678133ab121fc54);
```

Then it works fine, how can I specify the FontAwesome dir so that I don't have to do this manual edit?

*UPDATE*

After some digging I found the file `./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/config.js` which has the following code

```
fileLoaderDirs: {
    images: 'images',
    fonts: 'fonts'
},
```

This seems to be where FontAwesome is getting it's dir from but is there any way to override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get FontAwesome to work with PostCSS but I was able to get it to work with SASS.

I have seen that there are a few different ways to setup SASS with Laravel 8 but I am just posting the method that worked for me in case it can help someone else.

First change css into scss

```
mv ./resources/css ./resources/sass
mv ./resources/sass/app.css ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

Then add TailwindCSS and FontAwesome imports to app.scss

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

$fa-font-path: "../webfonts";  // this might be the missing piece that doesn't work without SASS
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
```

Change `webpack.mix.js` to the following

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .copy('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts')
    .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .options ({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [ tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ]
    });
```

Compile with `npm run production`

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to go so far to get it working, at least I didn't have to.

This was my config laravel mix config file after installing tailwindcss, since tail wind uses postcss. This are steps you take after you install tailwindcss and font-awesome.

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
     require('postcss-import'),
     require('tailwindcss'),
     require('autoprefixer'),
 ]);
```

After adding installing font-awesome, I just added this line

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ])
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css') // transpiling app.scss
    .copy( // copying fonts directory 
        'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts',
        'public/webfonts'
    ).sourceMaps();
```

then I had a sass file in `resoures/sass/app.scss` with the font-awesome import, since font-awesome is added using sass.

```sass
// Fontawesome
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands"
```

My `app.css` file inside `resources/css/app.css` looks like this

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

after that just run the npm command to compile

```node
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel Mix in a project without Laravel and I was having this problem with Font Awesome. After several hours of searching, I was able to solve the issue (I think):

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix.options({
    fileLoaderDirs: {
        images: 'dist/images',
        fonts: 'dist/fonts'
    }
});

mix
    .postCss("assets/css/app.css", "dist")
    .js("assets/js/app.js", "dist")
    .sourceMaps();
```